# How to write this equation ?¨

Tags: logic

I am not sure how to approach this problem. I would to make an equation to check which of the followings solutions are correct: 
1) Y = 2X or 2) Y = X

What I know is :

if X is 2 or less than 2 => 2X + Y = 1 if ( Y = 2X or Y = X ? )

if X are more than 2 => 3X + Y = 1

if we only have 1 X then X + Y = 1

Please, how can I incorporate that in only one equation ?

Comment: HI! Welcome to MSE, can you please explain with more details the question? I really didn't get the text of the problem

Answer (score 1):

> I would to make an equation to check which of the followings solutions
>   are correct :  1) Y = 2X or 2) Y = X

The solutions to these equations can be interpreted as two straight lines in the $x$-$y$-plane.

> is X is 2 or less than 2 => 2X + Y = 1 if ( Y = 2X or Y = X ? )
>
> if X are more than 2 => 3X + Y = 1

This sounds like a piecewise defined curve, it consists of two straight lines, with discontinuous jump at $x=2$. I see no relationship to the two lines given above.

> if we only have 1 X then X + Y = 1

I do not understand this. What does "if we only have 1 X" mean?